# Multiple select value alerts half value

Tags: javascript, multi-select

I would like Javascript to alert the whole employee name (first and last names) but with this code, it only shows the first name for some reason. Any Ideas on how to fix this problem?

Here's my code:

```
if ( $even1 % 2) 
    echo "<option value=". $employee_firstname . " " . $employee_lastname . ">". $employee_firstname . " " . $employee_lastname . "</option>";
else
    echo "<option value=". $employee_firstname . " " . $employee_lastname . ">". $employee_firstname . " " . $employee_lastname . "</option>";
```

The javascript:

```
var List = document.getElementById('slcEmp');
var x = 0;

for (x = 0; x < List.length; x++) {
    if (List[x].selected) {
        alert(List[x].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` doesn't return an array, it just returns one element.

Comment: Well, the code returns all the first names of the employees I select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the attribute value in quotes, since it contains a space:

```
echo "<option value='". htmlentities($employee_firstname) . " " . htmlentities($employee_lastname) . "'>". $employee_firstname . " " . $employee_lastname . "</option>";
                    ^                                                                                 ^
```

You should also use `htmlentities()` in case the name contains special characters (e.g. `O'Leary`).